# Http Get being ignored in rake task on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have the following http get task:

```
 stubhubapi1 = HTTParty.get(URI.encode('https://api.stubhub.com/search/catalog/events/v3/?parking=false&status=active&fieldList=id,name,description,eventUrl,eventDateLocal,ticketInfo,imageUrl&sort=popularity&desc&allowedViewingDomain=stubhub.co.uk&q=' + tmname + '&date=' + tmdate + ' TO ' + apidate + ''), headers: {"Authorization" => "Bearer bunchoflettershere"}).parsed_response
  if stubhubapi1.present?
    if stubhubapi1['numFound'].present?
    if stubhubapi1['numFound'] > 0
      stubhubid = stubhubapi1['events'].first['id']
    end
    end
  end
```

Now everything such as tmname tmdate and apidate is working as expected. It even works locally. However if I go and run the rake task on the web it isn't working. (I know this as I can check the db and its not populating the column)

Any ideas why?

Comment: what do you see in the response? use `puts stubhubapi1.inspect` right after HTTParty.get

Comment: Access Denied</H1>\n \nYou don't have permission to access That might be the issue :D Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you set your Stubhub API key on Heroku?

Comment: i have a stubhub key in heroku set yes. I don't have the bearer set